# How to login into website using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, web, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to login to this website and I keep getting this error:

```
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError (404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for ...
```

I followed the documentation and changed the user agent but still have this problem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'


USERNAME = 'myemail'
PASSWORD = 'mypassword'


mechanize = Mechanize.new
mechanize.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'
login_page = mechanize.get('https://bookcoverzone.com/')

form = login_page.forms[1]
form['email'] = USERNAME
form['password'] = PASSWORD
result = form.submit
```

Comment: Is the error on the login_page call or the form.submit call?

Comment: It might be that there’s only 1 form on the page, but you’re getting login_page.forms[1], which would be the second form on the page. Try using login_page.forms[0] instead?

Comment: There are four forms on the page. and `login_page.forms[1]` is the login form, and it fails on `form.submit`.

Comment: "404" errors tell us the server couldn't find the page, but, they can be generated by the server programmatically based on other criteria. In other words, they might be sensing something about the connection, then telling the server to reject the request and use 404 instead of one of the authentication error codes like 403. https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html